# How to extend Memcached item lifetime without getting it?

Tags: memcached, object-lifetime, lifetime

Can I extend a lifetime of a Memcached item without actually getting it?

Sure, I can get the item, set it again and increase a lifetime.
However, this way I'll have to copy the object to script's memory first, which is not good from the perfomance prospective.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you probably just want to not set a TTL at all (use 0) and let the LRU evict things that you aren't accessing.  If you don't intend to access the items at all, then why do you care if they're there?

Comment: Many have this impression that they can use memcached as some kind of semi-permanent storage, which I gather is not the case.

Comment: Yes, but this way memcached will capture all the available memory. First of all, I would prefer my server to have a reserve of mem. And I'm not sure, but wouldn't it make memcached work slower if it'd have to free the memory before storing anything.

Comment: The thing is that I want to store user's data in it once a user is logged in. I want them to be there until the user is active (extend TTL on every user's query). However I wouldn't want to pull this data all the time.

Comment: No, it will cause memcached to use as much memory as you configure it to have.  The answer to your question is to set the expiration to 0 and let the LRU pick it up.  memcached won't use more memory than you give it regardless of what you set for a TTL.